# implement datetimepicker to vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, datetimepicker, vuetify.js

I want to using datetimepicker from xdan    https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker. Because it suits my needs. but My problem is I use vue. More precisely vuetify https://vuetifyjs.com/en/. i want to implement that. but I doubt if it can be done. so I'm asking here to ask for opinions

Is the datepicker from xdan can be entered into vuetify? or maybe in vuetify there are such components?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this component.
It uses vuetify datepicker and timepicker.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify-datetime-picker

Comment: See the timepicker. It's different

Comment: Try this one:  https://github.com/chronotruck/vue-ctk-date-time-picker

Comment: I want like this : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/consulting-and-support. For example select "2 hour consulting session" and select date. It display time. Seems it using vuetify component. Because it is on the vuetify website. But i'm still confused to implement it

Comment: @positivethinking that's calendly